Why is properness a good analogue of compactness in scheme theory?
Let $X$ be a $Z$-scheme, i.e. equip $X$ with a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Z$. Then $X$ is proper over $Z$ if it is separated over $Z$, of finite type over $Z$, and if $f$ is universally closed.
Why is this a good analogue for compactness in the topological sense? In general, schemes that "should not be" compact are compact in the topological sense of the word, like the affine plane over $\mathbb C$, is compact but since this is the algebraic geometer's version of the $\mathbb C^n$ it really ought not to be. I remember being introduced to properness as a "good analogue" of compactness in scheme theory, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.
I was also introduced to separatedness being a good analogue of Hausdorfness, however this does make sense to me. We essentially realize that cartesian products don't really exist in the category of schemes unless we fix a base scheme $Z$, and then we just translate the equivalent definition of Hausdorfness (i.e. the diagonal is closed) into this setting.
If we are doing something like that for proper schemes over a fixed base scheme, what is the equivalent definition?
Edit: To clear up what I meant about separateness, I meant we cannot take a naive cartesian product in the set theoretic sense and endow it with a scheme structure so that it fulfills the role of the direct product in the category of schemes. What we can do is take a fibre product over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$ or take a fibre product over $Z$ in the category of $Z$-schemes, these then fill the role of the direct product in the respective categories. Being separated as analogue of being Hausdorff is now extremely clear, but I don't get how being proper over a base scheme or over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$ gives us the same thing as compactness.

You might want to skim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map, which explains quite a bit. It's basically the same idea as with separatedness (rephrase the set theoretic definition as something about maps, then translate into AG), just a bit more complicated since you already have to deal with separated vs. Hausdorff and finite type vs. locally compact.

What do you mean by "cartesian products don't really exist in the category of schemes unless we fix a base scheme"? The role of $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ in the definition of separated scheme is just that it is the terminal object in the category of schemes. In any category with a terminal object $1$, the product $X\times Y$ is the same as the fiber product $X\times_1 Y$.

@AlexKruckman Presumably the OP meant that the underlying-space functor $|\cdot|\colon \mathbf{Sch}\to \mathbf{Top}$ doesn't commute with products as this is the operative thing for his explanation (although I agree his wording makes it seem like they may be confused).
OP, to amplify Tabes Bridges correct answer it's useful to consult the following Stacks Project tag, which essentially summarizes some relevant theory from Bourbaki. This shows that if you interpret all the words in AG opposed to topology, then the definitions are the same. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/005M

@AlexKruckman I have added an edit in response to your comment, I realize I messed up with the terminology a bit.

@TabesBridges So it's really an analogue of a proper map, and not a scheme over a base scheme being compact?

@Chris I think you might benefit from thinking through your last comment: what does it mean for a scheme over a base scheme to 'be compact'? If you just mean that the source scheme is compact, then this has nothing to do with the base scheme. Evidently if you want to involve both you want some sort of 'relative compactness' -- that for $X\to S$, one has that $X$ is 'compact relative to $S$'. This is precisely the idea of what a proper map is.
